# Is there a name for a pre-loaded AJAX object?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there a name for a pre-loaded AJAX object stored in memory?

If I wanted to use this code:

```
function GetXML() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "questions.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {

        } //close success
    });//close AJAX     
}; //close function GetXML
```

to load some XML, how would I store this data on an object? Would I have to create a new variable on the object to store this XML? That's what I've found. If so, what would the type would the variable be? (e.g. String, Int, something of that nature)

Would it be '`Object XML`'  or something of that sort?

Thanks, Elliot Bonneville

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are setting `dataType: 'xml'` in the AJAX request, jQuery will parse the response into an `XMLDocument` object.

Note that [there are certain circumstances](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests) where you will need to do this manually. (Related to an IE bug, of course)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a JavaScript XML parser to convert it to an object.  There are a lot of pre-made ones, but if you want it for something simple check: http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp

Comment: Is it really that complicated? All I need to do is store the data (in any format) in a variable. Is that what I have to do?

Comment: With XML yes, you have to find some way to parse the data returned.  If you can change the format it's coming in from the back-end that would be an easier solution.

Comment: I've seen another programmer simply store the data in a variable though... I just don't recall how it's done. He was able to search the variable any way he wanted as if it was still an XML file. Are you absolutely sure that you have the change the format? I saw this just the other day, there's no way I could be mistaken. We were going over some of his code together.

Comment: The XML has to be parsed in Javascript some way.  Using someone elses parser is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll just have to accept your answer and the fact I can't do what I wanted to.

Comment: @wajiw is mistaken, jQuery will do this for you. _Usually_ this will result in an XMLDocument object; see my answer below.

Comment: jQuery natively doesn't convert it to an object that's easy to use, you still have to sift through the XMLDOM Object.  I did however find a plugin that may work for you using jquery: http://jparse.kylerush.net/

Comment: No, actually, Adam was referring to what I saw my friend do... It works. Thanks for the help, however, I'm going to have to accept his answer. (+1 for responding)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery already, parse the data like you parse the elements of an html document with regular $() calls on elements in the xml.

you could use jQuery('example